# Get ID of input when looking for changes on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several input and options which i am wanting to handle with a single method.
My input forms are defined as:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Layout">
        <br>
        <p>Please enter the physical layout</p>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Width</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="width" value ="1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Height</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="height" value="1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="unit">
                    <option>Panels</option>
                    <option>Metres</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Rigging</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="rigging">
                    <option>Flown</option>
                    <option>Ground Stack</option>
                    <option>None</option>
                </select>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Power">
        <br>
        <p>Please enter the power supply</p>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="amps">
                    <option>13A</option>
                    <option>16A</option>
                    <option>32A</option>
                    <option>63A</option>
                    <option>125A</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="phase">
                    <option>Single Phase</option>
                    <option>Three Phase</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Video">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am then trying to use the following to select what has changed:

```
/* get form changes */
$('.form-group').change(function(){
   switch($(this).attr("id")){
    case "width":
       alert("Width has changed");
       break;

   case "height":
        alert("Height has changd");
        break;

    case "unit":
           alert("Unit has changed");
           break;
   }
});
```

Comment: The `div` element doesn't fire up a `change` event.

Comment: `.form-group` is div tag i think you need `.form-control`

Comment: I think your plan was to observe `$('.form-control')` instead.

Comment: @MelanciaUK But onchange event still bubbles http://jsfiddle.net/24evsdrq/

Comment: @A.Wolff Good point. I forgot about the propagation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply your event with your form-control class because you are input and select field (so you don't just use input selector).

```
 /* get form changes */
    $('.form-control').change(function(){
       switch($(this).attr("id")){
         case "width":
            alert("Width has changed");
         break;

         case "height":
           alert("Height has changd");
         break;

         case "unit":
           alert("Unit has changed");
         break;
       }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword

```
$('.form-group').find('input').change(function () {
    // When the input value get changed the below code will be executed
    console.log(this.id);
    // Based on it add your switch statement
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ID on SELECT are the same in the case, and I chage this $('.form-group select').

```
$('.form-group select').change(function(){
   switch($(this).attr("id")){
    case "rigging":
       alert("Width has changed");
       break;

   case "power":
        alert("Height has changd");
        break;

    case "phase":
           alert("Unit has changed");
           break;
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cvhd0dny/

Answer (score 0):

Select option need to be changed to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-group').find('input').change(function() {
        switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
            case "width":
                console.log('Width chaged');
                break;

            case "height":
                 console.log("Height changed");
                break;

            case "unit":
                 console.log("Unit changed");
                break;

        }
    });
});
```